# What can I use as an ON/OFF switch for an AC circuit?

Tags: microcontroller, ac, switches

I am building a device which be taking voltage measurements in an AC circuit. As part of the circuit design I want to have a feature that enables me to switch off the circuit when I am not taking measurements and turn the circuit on when I want to take a measurement.

Ideally I would like the switch to be electronically controlled so it can be automated by a microcontroller such as a Raspberry Pi.

I am new to electronics and am wondering what the easiest way is to do this.

Comment: A switch you can control is called a [relay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relay). But it’s not clear to me here you want to insert that switch, given that voltage measurements are done in parallel. Is it the measuring branch you want to switch off, or the circuit being measured?

Comment: Use a Relay.  And what voltage is the AC???

Comment: Obligatory warning: mains power can be deadly. Be sure to take precautions.

Comment: @jcaron The voltage is 6VAC. It is the entire circuit that I want to be switched off. I'm studying resistance of different materials so effectively I'm taking voltage divider measurements. When I'm not taking a measurement I want to switch the whole circuit off to avoid extensive damage to the material. Would an SSR be what I'm looking for? I can apply DC voltage from a microcontroller to it and it will turn the circuit on or something of the sort

Comment: Why do you want to switch off the circuit; it's only taking measurements and can probably be left on. Do you have a reason?

Comment: @Andyaka To avoid extensive damage to the material. Right now it won't be a problem but I intend to use this for chemical samples in the future

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use electromagnetic relays with gold plated contacts.

[image]

Comment: And never pass a "high" current through them ever. Once you do, consider them no longer good for low current signals. That is, of course, your measuring application is low current to begin with. If it's not then there's no point to precious metal contacts. If the relay is for actually supplying power and not the measurement signal gold contacts shouldn't matter.

Comment: @DKNguyen - You're right.

Comment: Thank you! I look into these

Answer (score 0):

All AC power handling equipment must be UL-Listed.  (as distinct from "UR Recognized", and as *very* distinct from "Sold on AliExpress").

Your best bet is to use a UL-Listed relay.  This can come in two forms:

- A plug-in "smart socket" that you control wirelessly, and sandwiches between the wall socket and your device plug.
- A UL Listed relay such as a RiB or Aube which is installed in a junction box according to the instructions, and contains a 12V or 24V coil relay inside.  The Aube even includes a small transformer, so you just have to short two wires that have 24 volts AC on them.  24 volts AC is a popular control voltage for thermostats, doorbells etc.